# What is proper way to protect CoreData DB with pin-code or password?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, core-data, aes

I am keeping some user data with CoreData in my App. This data should be protected to prevent access from other people. Owner should be able easily get access to his data, for example with 4 pin code like on iPhone's lock screen.

I was thinking about AES encryption of CoreData DB file, and password for it is 4-digit pin-code.

But is it reliable method? 4digit pin can be brute-forced with 5 seconds i guess. So this is kind of 'protection from fools', am i right?
Then i have option to use strong (6-8 letters) password other than 4-digit. But user have to input it each time he opens the App, so it's not very user-friendly way to solve the problem.

Can anybody take me some advice, which options i have? 
And how i can use Apple's Keychain in these scheme?

Comment: Maybe use `LAContext` to request a TouchID or passcode authorization?

Answer (score 1):

How about generating a long random 'salt' string and keep that in the keychain? That is, you can prefix this with user input key(4 digit) and encrypt the data.. This way, only way to crack it, by trying all combinations of the 4 digits from the app OR try the combination of that unknown long key from a system on the encrypted file(If they could extract it from app sandbox, though its not very difficult).

Note:- Even keychain is not hack-proof but a better option..

Comment: Nice. I came to using difficult password in keychain to wrap/unwrap file. And 4 digit pin will be such an "interface protection" from random users. Did you mean this way?

Comment: Yes, its almost same what I meant. What I was saying is, if user pin is 1234 and random salt is abcdefghijk, then can combine both (1234abcdefghijk) and use it to encrypt the file. Its a kind of double protection. But changing user PIN(1234) will be an added head ache to handle.

Comment: Yep, so i think it's unnecessary to add pin to password. It will be ok if PIN serves just as screen lock.